# Flutter : how to return correctly from navigation?

Tags: flutter

I'm using navigation to go to a new page which downloads a chosen file. But after `Navigator.pop()` I end up with just a  blank white screen.

This is the code, including the button and navigation to the download screen:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text(widget.title),
    ),
    body: MyMap(
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        _navigateToFileDownload(context);
      },
      tooltip: 'New File',
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
    ),
  );
} 
void _navigateToFileDownload(BuildContext context) async {
  final result = await Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => Downloader(),
    ));
    setState(() {
      filePath = result;
    });
}
```

In the download class, for a succesful download I have this:

```
setState(() {
    downloading = false;
    progress = "Download Completed.";
    path = dirloc + randid.toString() + ".kmz";
    Navigator.pop(context,path);
  });
```

I can't see any errors in the logcat. The code never reaches `setState` to set the filePath. What am I missing?

[Edit] full source of the downloader below. Most of this was from another SO answer

```
Widget doDownload() {
  return MaterialApp(
    title: "File Downloader",
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: FileDownloader(),
    theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
  );
}
class Downloader extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: doDownload(),

    );
  }
}
class FileDownloader extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FileDownloaderState createState() => _FileDownloaderState();
}

class _FileDownloaderState extends State<FileDownloader> {

  final kmzUrl = "https://quilkin.co.uk/wandrer/cornwall-1.kmz";
  bool downloading = false;
  var progress = "";
  var path = "No Data";
  var platformVersion = "Unknown";
  Permission permission1 = Permission.storage;
  var _onPressed;
  static final Random random = Random();
  Directory externalDir;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    downloadFile();
  }
  Future<void> downloadFile() async {
    Dio dio = Dio();
    if (await Permission.storage.request().isDenied) {
      await Permission.storage.request();
    }
    if (await Permission.storage.status.isGranted) {
      String dirloc = "";
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        //dirloc = "/sdcard/download/";
        dirloc = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
      } else {
        dirloc = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
      }

      var randid = random.nextInt(10000);

      try {
        FileUtils.mkdir([dirloc]);
        await dio.download(kmzUrl, dirloc + randid.toString() + ".kmz",
            onReceiveProgress: (receivedBytes, totalBytes) {
              setState(() {
                downloading = true;
                progress =
                    ((receivedBytes / totalBytes) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%";
              });
            });
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }

      setState(() {
        downloading = false;
        progress = "Download Completed.";
        path = dirloc + randid.toString() + ".kmz";
        Navigator.pop(context,path);
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        progress = "Permission Denied!";
        _onPressed = () {
          downloadFile();
        };
      });
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('File Downloader'),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: downloading
              ? Container(
            height: 120.0,
            width: 200.0,
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.black,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Downloading File: $progress',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
              : Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(path),
              MaterialButton(
                child: Text('Request Permission Again.'),
                onPressed: _onPressed,
                disabledColor: Colors.black12,
                color: Colors.pink,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                height: 40.0,
                minWidth: 100.0,
              ),
            ],
          )));
}
```

Comment: Can you add code of a second screen?

Comment: OK,  done. Most of it is from another SO answer; I've only really changed the first dozen lines, and added Navigator.pop() to the setState().

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call setState if you pop the widget.
You can simply call the .pop(context, path)
If your second class reaches the `pop` method, it should work.

**EDIT**: seeing your code:
The problem that you create a second MaterialApp in your Downlaoder class that mess up with the navigator.
You can remove the Downloader class and build the FileDownloader class directly, or  instead of `MaterialApp` use `Scaffold` in your `Downloader` class.

Comment: I wondered about having to use setState, and only added it as a possible solution to the problem. So the problem exisrts with or without setState(). The code definately reaches the pop(), and the file is downloaded and stored correctly.

Comment: Yes, that was it, the new MaterialApp was causing the problem.